# becomeFirstResponder - Purpose of returned value

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, return-value, becomefirstresponder

```
self.textField_name.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This line has a `Bool` return type. Though worrying about this is not significant, however I was just thinking about it as to what is the purpose of returning a value from `becomeFirstResponder`. Putting it in another way - How can be the returned value from `becomeFirstResponder` be used ? So far I know that `becomeFirstResponder` makes the `UITextField/UITextView` active. In a way we just want to show the keyboard. And nothing as such is required in return.

It might seem silly but will clear two things - why is a return type for this required? And will remove the warning "Result of call to becomeFirstResponder() is unused" (in a lighter mood :))

Comment: I think you can remove the warning by let _ = self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: @user1000 : Ya that was just to lighten up :) The real question I have is, how can I use the returned value of this function and is the return type really required for this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation of becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder)

> **Return Value**
>   true if this object is now the first-responder or false if it is not.

That's because `UIResponder` (of which UI elements are subclasses of) does not necessarily *have* to become first responder. It has `canBecomeFirstResponder` method, which may return `NO` (or `false`) - in fact, it returns `NO` (or `false`) by default. If you subclass `UIResponder`, you may wish that your class shouldn't be a first responder and if you don't override `canBecomeFirstResponder`, it won't.